# How to get reference to a pop up window and load a javascript file in it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint-2010

In SharePoint 2010, there is a button to open a popup window (its for `alerts`). However it doesn't use the conventional way to open a popup window like `window.open`, it calls a SharePoint function, which results in a pop up window opening. Now is there a way I can load a JavaScript file (`.js` file using a script tag basically) in it? I figure I would need to get a reference to that window somehow, and then append a script tag in it or something.

Note: I can't modify the actual file popup window page. I just want to dynamically insert the JavaScript in it programmatically.

Comment: can you post the `SharePoint` function?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the `SharePoint` function opens the window.  Unless it opens it as an assignment to a variable you can access for reference, then there's no way to access it. Chances are you are going to need to modify the `SharePoint` function to do this and return that reference or else make it a globally scoped variable you can then reference. Also, the target window will have to be the same domain as the parent page.